# I need to access the datagridview of first form to fill the second form's datagridview

Tags: windows, forms

I have two forms. The first form contains a datagridview. I have a datagridview in second form as well. On loading my second form I need to get the first row of datagridview of first form into second form's datagridview.

Comment: You need to show what you have tried so far.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There are very many articles explaining how to access other forms of an application.